# SslStream on TCP Server fails to validate client certificate with RemoteCertificateNotAvailable

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate, tcpclient, sslstream

This question is all about solving a `SslPolicyError.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable` error.

I have developed a TCP Server with SSLStream and a TCP Client for the other end.

I authenticate the server with:

```
sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer
```

I authenticate the client with:

```
sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient
```

I am loading my client certificate from `Trusted Publishers - Local Machine`.

Both are running on the same machine.

I tried loading the client certificate from the .cer and .pfx files rather than the trusted publishers store. But the server's client (remote) certificate validator callback fails by finding that `SslPolicyErrors` has a `RemoteCertificateNotAvailable` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link didn't come through, but there's a problem I can spot with the statment:
"I loaded my client certificate from Trusted Publishers"

*Client* certificates (i.e. those including *Client Authentication* in their Enhanced Key Usage field) typically live in the **Personal** store for a user account. You always need a private key for a certificate in order to "be" the entity from that certificate.

Same with *Server* certificates (which have a different Intended Purpose OID associated with them, though - *Server Authentication*). It'd be odd for you to have a cert *with a private key* available in the **Trusted Publishers** store, I think.

If you double-click a client or server certificate in CertMgr.msc , you should see a *This certificate has a private key*-type message towards the bottom.

If you don't, you only have half a key pair - signatures and authentication require the private key. (The server cert needs a private key at the server end, and the client cert needs a private key at the client end.)

Comment: I have also tried loading the certificate from "Personal" store.
My certificate do have private key.

Comment: Certutil -verify -urlfetch should validate whether the certificate is able to be validated correctly. If not, no dice.

The server cert needs "intended purpose: server authentication" and the client cert will probably need "client authentication", if it's meant to uniquely identify a client.

Comment: Tristank. You have spotted the problem actually. I was having a certificate with purpose of only server auth. I needed the certificate which supports client auth. So, once I got that, it worked.